# Jquery mouseover function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have this Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Do menu mouseovers
    $('.bar a').each(function() {

        var Link = $(this);
        var LinkID = Link.attr("ID");

        $('.menu-pop').each(function() {
            var PopID = $(this).attr("data-for");

            // We have found a match, assign events
            if (PopID == LinkID) {

                Link.mouseover = (function() {
                    alert("trucks lol");
                });

                return;
            }
        });

    });

});
```

It's for a popup menu I'm writing.  The simplified structure of the menu is:

```
<div class="bar">
    <a class="item">Home</a>
    <a class="item" id="mnuAnother">Another Link</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-pop" data-for="mnuAnother">
    Links and stuff
</div>
```

I'm expecting it to do the alert when my mouse goes over the "Another" link, but at present it throws no errors/no alert.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
Link.mouseover(function() {
  alert("trucks lol");
});
```

(using jQuery's mouseover function which is a shortcut for binding the mouseover event)

Comment: You need `Link` instead of `link`.

Answer (score 1):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/rQ72v/

Change this:

```
Link.mouseover = (function() {
    alert("trucks lol");
});
```

to this:

```
Link.mouseover(function() {
    alert("trucks lol");
});
```

`Link.mouseover =` doesn't really make any sense.

Perhaps `Link.onmouseover =` would work (or would you need `Link[0].onmouseover =`?) in terms of raw JavaScript.

But, it's much better to use jQuery's [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

Comment: Hi @thirtydot can you help me with this one please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835128/jquery-onmouseover-selection-attribute/31835344#31835344

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the

```
// ...
$('.bar a').each(function() {
    var Link = $(this);
// ...
```

by something line

```
// ...
$('.bar a').each(function(item) {
    var Link = $(item);
// ...
```

Comment: That's valid jQuery, though ("The value can also be accessed through the this keyword" http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ ), so through it probably isn't the cause of his problem.